# PHP: Put URLs in database after upload with Plupload ( Amazon S3, Plupload)

Tags: php, url, upload, amazon-s3, plupload

Finally my code is working for uploading images to my Amazon S3 bucket and giving them unique file names. But now I dont know how to put the URLs of the uploaded images into a MySQL database. Who can help me?

---

Here I will place the code of my different files, because I discovered many people are having trouble using Plupload to upload images to their Amazon S3 bucket.

**crossdomain.xml**
Placed in the root of the Amazon S3 bucket.

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM “http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd”>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain=”*”/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**photos.php**
Uploading photos

```
<?php 
/* 
In order to upload files to S3 using Flash runtime, one should start by placing crossdomain.xml into the bucket.

In our tests SilverLight didn't require anything special and worked with this configuration just fine. It may fail back
to the same crossdomain.xml as last resort.

!!!Important!!! Plupload UI Widget here, is used only for demo purposes and is not required for uploading to S3.
*/

// important variables that will be used throughout this example
$bucket = 'BUCKET';

// these can be found on your Account page, under Security Credentials > Access Keys
$accessKeyId = 'KEY';
$secret = 'SECRET';

// hash_hmac — Generate a keyed hash value using the HMAC method 
// (PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, PECL hash >= 1.1)
if (!function_exists('hash_hmac')) :
// based on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php#39492
function hash_hmac($algo, $data, $key, $raw_output = false)
{
    $blocksize = 64;
    if (strlen($key) > $blocksize)
        $key = pack('H*', $algo($key));

    $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
    $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
    $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
    $hmac = pack('H*', $algo(($key^$opad) . pack('H*', $algo(($key^$ipad) . $data))));

    return $raw_output ? $hmac : bin2hex($hmac);
}
endif;

// prepare policy
$policy = base64_encode(json_encode(array(
    // ISO 8601 - date('c'); generates uncompatible date, so better do it manually
    'expiration' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z', strtotime('+1 day')),  
    'conditions' => array(
        array('bucket' => $bucket),
        array('acl' => 'public-read'),
        array('starts-with', '$key', ''),
        // for demo purposes we are accepting only images
        array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'image/'),
        // "Some versions of the Adobe Flash Player do not properly handle HTTP responses that have an empty body. 
        // To configure POST to return a response that does not have an empty body, set success_action_status to 201.
        // When set, Amazon S3 returns an XML document with a 201 status code." 
        // http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTFlash.html
        array('success_action_status' => '201'),
        // Plupload internally adds name field, so we need to mention it here
        array('starts-with', '$name', ''),  
        // One more field to take into account: Filename - gets silently sent by FileReference.upload() in Flash
        // http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTFlash.html
        array('starts-with', '$filename', ''), 
    )
)));

// sign policy
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $policy, $secret, true));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<BASE HREF="http://www.yourwebsite.com/">
<title>Plupload to Amazon S3 Example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load plupload and all it's runtimes and finally the UI widget -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.gears.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.silverlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.flash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.browserplus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.html4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/plupload.html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_assets/js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>

<h1>Plupload to Amazon S3 Example</h1>

<div id="uploader">
    <p>You browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        runtimes : 'flash,silverlight',
        url : 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/<?php echo $bucket; ?>/',
        max_file_size : '10mb',

        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: {
            'key': 'photos/<?php echo time(); ?>.jpg', // use filename as a key
            'Filename': '${filename}', // adding this to keep consistency across the runtimes
            'acl': 'public-read',
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'AWSAccessKeyId' : '<?php echo $accessKeyId; ?>',       
            'policy': '<?php echo $policy; ?>',
            'signature': '<?php echo $signature; ?>'
        },

        // !!!Important!!! 
        // this is not recommended with S3, since it will force Flash runtime into the mode, with no progress indication
        resize : {width : 100, height : 100, quality : 60},  // Resize images on clientside, if possible 

        // optional, but better be specified directly
        file_data_name: 'file',

        // re-use widget (not related to S3, but to Plupload UI Widget)
        multiple_queues: true,

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            {title : "JPEG files", extensions : "jpg"}
        ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '_assets/js/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '_assets/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you find solution for this? i'm working in the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the Plupload FileUploaded callback:

```
init : {

            // FileUploaded is called when a file has been uploaded, and contains all info about the file
        FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
        // add an ajax call here to store the data in db

    },

},
```

I don't know what your level of experience is, so I'll elaborate some more:

The ajax call could be something like this:

```
$.post( "test.php", { file: file} );
```

This would post the file data to a php page (test.php) where you can insert the data into the database